# Boolean tool issue after difference

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

I'm new to Blender but have this issue after trying to make a difference with boolean tool with shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> cant see the cutter wireframe and can't modify the cutter too.

[image]

Comment: Just use Ctrl numpad -. See my answer below

Comment: think of the CTRL SHIFT shortcut as a destructive boolean, meaning the cutter object will be consumed in the process and the cut object's mesh will be modified. The CTRL only shortcut is non-desctructive, and a modifier is added afterwards.

Comment: @Gorgious Yes I agree. In fact I reckon that the description for the Bool Tool addon in the [Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/object/bool_tools.html?utm_source=blender-3.6.2#description) should be rewritten as it's not at all clear there, particuarly for a newcomer to Blender!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Bool tool, you select the Cylinder, Shift-select the Cube then use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>Numpad<kbd>-</kbd> That should produce this result:

[image]

If you use the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key at the same time the boolean cylinder **will** disappear because it actually applies the modifier and deletes the cylinder.

In that image I've clicked on the bounding box of the Cylinder to select it, but you could also click the Cylinder in the top-right Outliner panel.

If you now <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode you'll be able to edit the cylinder as normal and the effect will show in the cube cutout back in <kbd>Object</kbd> mode.

[image]

Comment: I've edited that slightly  to remove the Shift key from the shortcut.